# How does Armadillo library handle error?

Tags: c++, armadillo

Just started on Armadillo library. Through out the documentation and FAQ, I didn't find any reference on how does Armadillo handle errors. For example, how should I know whether "mat A(1e10, 1e10)" is successful or not?

Comment: Some of the functions and constructors throw `std::logic_error` as the documentation states

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error handling mechanism of Armadillo is not clear from its documentation. By email communication with the author Sanderson, it's figured out that the error handling mechanism of Armadillo is actually a mixture of C++ std exception and C-style return value. However, the information of what exception will be thrown is still incomplete in the documentation.

For example, to define a matrix, I'll suggest not using "mat X(M, N)" because there is no error handling. The safe way is like this (C-style):

```
  mat X;
  try{
      X.set_size(M, N);
  } catch (...) {
      printf("memory allocation failed\n");
      return -1;
  }
```

Note that when memory allocation error occurs, exception "std::logic_error" or "std::bad_alloc" will be thrown (see the comment below by mtall), this is not put in the documentation. When return, use "X.reset()" to release the data memory.

And @mtall: I suggest a less harsh attitude to newbies of a specific field is better for the community health. Force others to read incomplete documentations is not a constructive opinion.In fact, most good open source projects come with documentations not so good, that's why we should help make them more clear and user-friendly.

Comment: @mtall: thanks for the comment.These're exactly info missing from the official documentation. I suggest maybe you can summarize your experience with Armadillo and make appendix to the official documentation

Comment: @mtall: Where did you see me "complaining"? Make it better doesn't mean a user cannot seek help. If I have to read through all the source codes to answer my question of a open-source project, I'd rather not use it. Write my own code is a much simpler task.

Answer (score 3):

Examples from Armadillo's [documentation](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html):

For `R = chol(X)` and `chol(R, X)` functions: if the decomposition fails, R is reset and `chol(X)` throws a *std::runtime_error* exception, while `chol(R,X)` returns a *bool* set to *false*.

For the `eig_sym(X)` and `inv(X)` functions: if X is not square, a *std::logic_error* exception is thrown.

For operators like `+`, a *std::logic_error* exception is thrown if incompatible object sizes are used.

For element access like `A(i,j)`, a *std::logic_error* exception is thrown if the requested element is out of bounds.

etc etc.

The source code for Armadillo is also available, so you can directly look at it and see what it does.